# Road Bike or Mountain

Tags: hybrid-bike

I have a 2014 Apollo Evade mountain bike that I have upgraded to ride on the roads for long journeys and commute. This bike now runs like a dream pretty fast for a bike that cost me £120 new plus £30 each for tyres (schwalbe city) and £50 each for lighter sports wheels. I roughly ride about 150 miles a week on average and have completed about 10k miles in 2 years. everyone I have spoken to suggest I should now upgrade to a road bike as it is more suited to my journeys but other than being lighter and quicker, what other advantages are there to me spending 5 times the amount that I have spent on my current bike? And I can cover 20 miles in 1 hour 10 mins on a MTB. And because of my good health and fitness I don't even feel tyred (ha ha) afterwards for riding something that quoted to be slow heavy and supposed to be used on mountains. What do you think is the best option stick with my MTB or go for a massive upgrade to a quality road bike? Please advise.

Comment: Can you borrow a road bike for a day ride?  That might demonstrate the differences better than long text answers.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Danny. As with all new members we recommend that you take the [tour] to make best use of the site. Re your bike, if it ain't broke don't fix it. Don't let others push you to buying sth you don't feel the need for. If you are riding with a bunch and getting left behind then I'd have different advice. The other aspect is price; £600 gets you a very low-end road bike. Wait until you have a real need, other than peer pressure.

Comment: If you do decide to buy a road bike, consider buying a quality used one.  Used bicycles can be a real bargain, if you know what's good and what to avoid.

Comment: The two things that are a problem with a typical "mountain" bike on the road are the tires (they need to be smoother and higher pressure, and maybe a hair narrower) and the suspension (if your mountain bike has that, and you can't lock it out).  Suspension eats up a lot of energy on the road.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you're doing fine with your existing bike, so you have no *need* to upgrade. So it's just a question of whether you'd be happier on a nicer bike. If a nicer bike will make you enjoy your cycling more, and you think that would be good value for money, go out and buy one. We can advise you about what features of a nicer bike might affect you but, ultimately, the best option is the one you like the most.

Comment: If you're considering commuting on a road bike, try this sort of ride before you buy - some people get on with it, but I found that having to choose between seeing over cars and covering the brakes wasn't for me. Potholes aren't great on skinny tyres either.

Comment: If you like to brag about your times, you are going to love the road bike. Also, get on strava for a cure of humility, I can cover 40k in 58 minutes :D

Answer (score 6):

Salesman: Certainly you should upgrade you bike. You will go faster, further and leap tall buildings in a single bound. Woman will throw themselves at you, men will be intimidated by you masculinity.

Financial Advisor: Buying a bike worth 5 times as much to do the same job your current bike does is not a prudent financial investment. You should stick to the bike you have that is working perfectly well for you.

I cannot tell you who to listen to. What I will say is  £120 is a pretty cheap bike (BSO) and it would almost certainly be better to spend money on a better bike than upgrading it further. If you are happy with your current bike, I suggest start saving for a new one then ride the old one until buying a new bike is less about worry about what it costs and more about looking forward to riding a better bike.

Answer (score 4):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it!

While the bike works and suits your usage, keep using it. Keep in mind that a cheap bike (which 120 pounds for an MTB certainly is) will need more service to keep it safe and functional. You'll likely want to upgrade once you start to wear it out. You'll have a better idea what to look for and (if you start saving now) a bit more money.

What that next bike should be like is up to you, but for commuting and longer trips I'd go for a touring bike - a rack and fenders make the bike way more comfortable to use and it will still end up faster than an equivalent MTB.

Also, don't buy a bike you cannot afford have stolen and get a good lock (10% of the price of the bike is recommended).

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Matej. Nice first post, keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise sticking with the mountain bike. I commute on one and a tourer which is basically the same thing but with road wheels.

I tried a road bike a couple of times, and it's not as comfortable and didn't seem all that much faster. And I just need a workhorse to get me from A to B, so comfort is a bigger factor than speed, I'm not racing anyone and I believe that I get just as much exercise as from a road bike if not more.

Answer (score -3):

This forum is like a bike calculator. My own terminology, but what I mean is that most of the regular contributors in this forum answer based on facts and calculations using their brain, not based on emotion and fashion. Whilst they are a very knowledgeable bunch, I feel like some of us are more keen to...ahem... splash the cash, splosh the dosh, blow the dough, spray some pay, or at least to buy things that are "nicer" rather than just being more functional and cost effective.

I however am severely materialistic, and I like to look downright peng when on my bike. So I would advise that if/when you can afford it, without it negatively impacting other important aspects of your life, then why not treat yourself to something a little tastier. You might be fast on your current set up, but you will be faster on a lighter, stiffer, more aero and potentially more suitably geared road bike, that's not an opinion it's the laws of physics. Maybe you aren't interested in going faster or in going the same speed for less effort, in which case you have very little to gain from getting a better bike, but c'mon? really?

Comment: Yep, answers are for facts. Comments are for other things.

Comment: @andy256 Uuhhh, well that's not at all true, a lot of answers are opinions. This question can only ultimately be answered with an opinion, just look at the other two answers. And that is the same with a lot of the questions on this forum, otherwise you can only answer the purely mechanically based questions.

Comment: Please explain - "like to look downright peng" ?   Penguin, smart and dapper in a tuxedo ?

Comment: @Paddy Almost every answer here has an element of opinion, but we want strong, fact based answers. Even "I did this and it worked for me" is a fact based answer. This answer would fit well on a chat site

Comment: @Criggie peng means sexy. I don't know where it comes from though